# B2C Salesforce integration fails with error IDPError:1605 Unable to resolve request into a Service Provider

Tags: salesforce

I am following the instructions on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom to set up Salesforce as an IDP and my B2C tenant as a service provider.

Everything look fine but when I try to test the flow (IEF Policy flow) I get and error on the Salesforce side with message Error: Unable to resolve request into a Service Provider

I have tried this integration with 3 other SAML IDPs as well and in all scenarios the IDP fails to recognize my Entity Id.

Any idea what is missing from my configurations?

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with the exact same issue, I was able to solve this problem by adding a new Item in the MetaData field of the Salesforce ClaimsProvider.
You have to add the following:

```
<Item Key="IssuerUri">(Entity ID that you entered in Salesforce Connected App)</Item>
```

The final ClaimsProvider code should be:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>salesforce</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Salesforce</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="salesforce">
      <DisplayName>Salesforce</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your Salesforce account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsSignedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://contoso-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/.well-known/samlidp.xml</Item>
        <Item Key="IssuerUri">https://your-tenant.b2clogin.com/your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="userId"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="username"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="SAMLIdp" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml-idp"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Make sure to modify the PartnerEntity and IssuerUri values to match your Salesforce Connected App.